# In Kotlin how do I implement a list of elements which each belong to the same super class defined using generics

Tags: list, kotlin, generics, inheritance, nested-lists

I have several closely related classes that are all derived from the same super class.

```
open class Fruit() {}

class Apple() : Fruit() {}

class Orange() : Fruit() {}
```

I need to perform certain operations on list of these classes.  They are the same operations, but need to be implemented differently. So one solution would be to use generics

```
abstract class <F>FilledBowl() {
    abstract var fruits: MutableList<F>
    abstract fun makeJuice(fruit: <F>)
}

class AppleFilledBowl() : <Apple>FilledBowl() {
    override var fruits = mutableListOf()
    override fun makeJuice(fruit: Apple) { 
//some implementation
    }
}

class OrangeFilledBowl() : <Orange>FilledBowl() {
    override var fruits = mutableListOf()
    override fun makeJuice(fruit: Orange) { 
//some implementation
    }
}
```

So far so good. Now I want a function that does something to a list of these classes.  I'm having trouble even declaring this.

```
fun process(bowls: MutableListOf<FilledBowl>) {
    for(bowl in bowls) makeJuice(bowl)
}
```

I understand that this doesn't work because FilledBowl is abstract, but I think it needs to be since I'm using a generic?  I tried to do this without generics like this

```
abstract class FilledBowl() {
    abstract var fruits: MutableList<Fruit>
    abstract fun makeJuice(fruit: Fruit)
}

class AppleFilledBowl() : FilledBowl() {
    override var fruits: MutableList<Apple> = mutableListOf()
    override fun makeJuice(fruit: Apple) { 
//some implementation
    }
}

class OrangeFilledBowl() : FilledBowl() {
    override var fruits: MutableList<Orange> = mutableListOf()
    override fun makeJuice(fruit: Orange) { 
//some implementation
    }
}
```

But in this case Apples and Oranges are not considered to be Fruit. I have a feeling that there should be a way to do this using the keywords out and in, but I'm not finding it.

Comment: This is hard topic and StackOverflow contributors may give you a spot answer, but I recommend you study the 3 articles by Dave Leeds on this topic starting with: https://typealias.com/guides/illustrated-guide-covariance-contravariance/

Comment: What is `makeJuice()` in `process()`? What do you want to do with each bowl in a list? Most importantly: if you receive a list of just `FilledBowl`, then how do you want to do anything with these bowls, if you don't know what are their exact types? I guess the only type-safe operation you can do here is to read the list of fruits in all bowls.

Comment: The example isn't quite cohesive enough to understand exactly what problem you want to solve. In your generics example, you're trying to pass FilledBowls to some unknown `makeJuice` function. You say that function's not working, but we don't know what it looks like. Or did you mean to call each FilledBowl's own `makeJuice` function? If that's the case, where will you get the fruit that goes into that function?